# Rails Tenant schema switching with background jobs not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-postgresql

Setting up a scheduled rake task using Whenever gem. 
Required to switch to a specific schema (Using Apartment gem in my project)

Code in config/schedule.rb

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
env :GEM_PATH, ENV['GEM_PATH']
set :output, "#{Whenever.path}/log/scheduler.log"
every 1.minute do
  rake "db:my_task"
end
```

Code in lib/tasks/my_task.rake

```
namespace :db do
  task :my_task => :environment do
    Apartment::Tenant.switch("subdomain") do
       #My Code here
    end
  end
end
```

Produces the following error in logs log/scheduler.logs

```
  rake aborted!
  Apartment::TenantNotFound: One of the following schema(s) is invalid: "subdomain" "public"
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/apartment-1.2.0/lib/apartment/adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:72:in `rescue in connect_to_new'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/apartment-1.2.0/lib/apartment/adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:65:in `connect_to_new'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/apartment-1.2.0/lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:91:in `block in switch!'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/apartment-1.2.0/lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:88:in `switch!'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/apartment-1.2.0/lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:105:in `switch'
/home/user1/Desktop/SPERICORN/kidversity/lib/tasks/dynamic_age_setter.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find schema kochi
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/apartment-1.2.0/lib/apartment/adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:66:in `connect_to_new'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/apartment-1.2.0/lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:91:in `block in switch!'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/apartment-1.2.0/lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:88:in `switch!'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/apartment-1.2.0/lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:105:in `switch'
/home/user1/Desktop/SPERICORN/kidversity/lib/tasks/dynamic_age_setter.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:dynamic_age_setter
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection.connection try this 
sample code below :

```
namespace :debtor_email_data_fix do
```

desc 'update data'

task email_normalize_to_downcase: :environment do
    create_connection_with_db
    Apartment::Tenant.switch!('app')

```
Email.find_each do |t|
  t.update(address: t.address.downcase)
end
```

end

task all: [:email_normalize_to_downcase] do
  end

private

def create_connection_with_db
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection.connection
  end
end